# Detect selected UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uitouch

How can I identify which `UIImageView` is currently touched in a view? The `UIImageViews` are created dynamically and are based on tags. I'll also be using the tags with the index of my objects and array for reference. I have read that I need to use `UIButton` for this kind of scenario but the problem with `UIButton` is I cannot drag it outside its own bounds.

I need to know how I can get the specific dynamically created button via tag so I can detect which `UIImageView` to move in the `TouchesMoved`.

Here is the code for creating the `UIImageViews` from my objects:

```
for (ObjectClass *obj in [self myDelegate].theObj)
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(obj._sX + (obj._sW / 2),obj._sY + (obj._sH / 2),10,10);
    handlerImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    handlerImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [[self view] addSubview:handlerImg];
    handlerImg.tag = z;
    [handlerImg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    z++;
}
```

Then my code for the touchesMoved event:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (drag == YES)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        ObjectClass *obj = [[self myDelegate].theObj objectAtIndex:currHandler]; //Get object based on selected UIImageView

        if ([touch view] == handlerImg) //Identify which UIImageView is selected
        {
            someImage.center=location;
```

Comment: When you are using tags then why you are unable to get imageview

Comment: Because I only get the UIImageView with the last tag.

Comment: So which tag you want the latest or it's previous

Comment: jeraldov, can you try creating a local UIImageView inside your for loop rather than using handlerImg ? I think you're overwriting the handlerImg UIImageView everytime in your for loop, maybe that's why the tag value is always the last value of your for loop. See if that helps.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra I actually want the tag of the selected or the UIImageView that is being tapped.

Comment: I think one hack for you. Put a button on each UIImageview with tag same as imageview and when your are touching the button just remove the button from it's superview and drag the image if you want then you can know which image is residing beneath under button. Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) //Identify which UIImageView is selected
        {
            someImage.center=location;
            //[touch view].tag here you'l get tag value.

        }
```

(OR)

use gestures,add gesture delegate in .h file and put this on ein for loop.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    tapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                   initWithTarget:self
                   action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [tapRecognizer release];
```

and put this one

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"KidsViewController ==> handleTap.");

    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer).view.tag)      
    {
         //do whatever you want here
    }

}
```